# Some Line Numbers Missing When Using linum

Tags: macos, emacs

I'm running Emacs 23.3.1 on Mac OS X. When I have linum-mode enable some lines are not numbered. Sometimes when my cursor scrolls past a line that is not numbered its number will appear and then sometimes it will disappear again. Is there away to prevent this from happening?

[image: Missing line numbers in linum-mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From your screenshot, it looks like lines with only comments are not numbered. Dunno why.
- Perhaps there is another overlay at such positions, and it has a higher priority, thus masking the line-number overlay.  Try turning off font-lock temporarily, to see whether that affects things.  Then try increasing the priority of the line-number overlays.  For a quick test, do this:

```
    (defun foo ()
      (dolist (ov  linum-overlays)
        (overlay-put ov 'priority 2000)))

    (add-to-list 'post-command-hook 'foo t t)
```

If that helps, then instead of that, do the `overlay-put` (but try with a ower priority, say, 200) in function `linum-update-window`.  IOW, add the priority when the overlay is put on the text.